# iterating through ajax result and variables not what expected

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

The results of getLocations.php is a json result of id&LocationName.  I created a concatenated result because there is other data being returned as well.

```
 {"1:LocationA":{"lat":"38.8737","lon":"-77.013"},"2:LocationB":{"lat":"38.9002","lon":"-77.0365"}


    $.ajax({
            type:"GET",
            url:"getLocations.php",
            dataType:"json",
            success:function(result){
                    $.each(result,function(e,i){
                            var titleLong = e.split("&");
                            title = titleLong[1];
                            id = titleLong[0];
                            alert(title) // 1st alert
                            $.ajax({
                                    type:"GET",
                                    data:"id="+id,
                                    url:"getData.php",
                                    success:function(result){
                                         alert(title)  //2nd alert
```

why doesnt the value of title traverse into the second ajax call.  if you look at first alert, it is what i would expect it to be. the variable retrieved during the each loop.  If you look at the second alert, it is only ever the last result of the each loop(LocationB)....my guess is a asynchroncity thing... i have tried both asynch:true and false.

what am i missing?

Comment: you should attempt to use `console.log()` when possible instead of alert

Answer (score 5):

By declaring `title` without using `var`, you are declaring it as a global variable. If you add `var` it will become a local variable and each inner AJAX call will have their own closure of the variable:

```
var title = titleLong[1];
```

Comment: I like when its simple!.